# When the browser window is resized, a horizontal scroll bar appears. On scrolling the bg color disappears from the scrolled area

Tags: html, css

All this works fine, until you make the window smaller to show a horizontal scrollbar. When you scroll horizontally, the revealed portion no longer has the background. Everything is back to normal after the screen is maximized.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background:#339900;">
            <div style="width:1000px; height:75px; background:#ff0000; margin:0px auto;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Solved code.. all thanks to Pyro -

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="min-width:100%; width:1000px; height:200px; background:#339900;"><!--width same as inner box-->
            <div style="width:1000px; height:75px; background:#ff0000; margin:0px auto;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand you, you want all the coloured stripes to fill the screen horizontally?

Comment: I ran it on JSFiddle, but you still need to explain what output you are wanting

Comment: The box with background green colour is 100% width and 200px height. On  that I have a box with 1000px width and 75px height. The problem is when I make the browser window small, I've a horizontal scroll and in that when I scroll horizontally, the green background which is 100% disappears.

Comment: So you want it so that when you scroll, it is the same length as the 1000px one?

Comment: What I want is when I scroll horizontally the green box which has a  height of (200px-75px) 125px more than the red box is still visible.

Comment: Why do the `1000px` items have to be `1000px`?

Comment: Please formulate your question properly so that it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the 4 colours, green and gray set to `100%`, this sets it to the width of the view-port. But red and black are `1000px`.

> "when I scroll horizontally, the green background which is 100% disappears"

This is because, imagine your window is `600px` wide, it is equivalent of doing:

```
width: 600px;
```

So when you scroll, because of the `1000px` wide div, the browser makes a scrollbar to view all 1000 of those pixels.

> "I know I can solve this with percentage but this is for a project where the width has to be fixed. Please help to fix this with 1000px width itself."

If the screen already has a scrollbar to the `1000px` and you don't want the `100%` colours to be not shown when you scroll, you could just set the `100%` to `1000px`, this way the colours stretch for the same length as the other colours.

Now, if the screen is wider than `1000px` and you want the `1000px` colours to cut off at that width, but the others to still fill whole width, then you could add:

```
min-width: 100%;
```

This would ensure that the colours always fill the whole screen.

Another option would be `position: fixed`, but this would only work if the colours were ALWAYS in the same spot (or you would need some JavaScript, but I wouldn't say it is worth it).

Comment: thanks Pyro for all your help... for now I am disabling the horizontal scroll in the body tag (overflow-x:hidden) as % won't solve my problem

Comment: No problem, so my answer didn't give you the desired result? Shame

Comment: Even when I use percentage for both the boxes and make the browser window small and scroll horizontally, the background colour still disappears. So, till I find a solution I'm disabling the horizontal scroll. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: "Even when I use percentage for both the boxes", did you not follow "you could just set the 100% to 1000px"?

Comment: My question covers that scenario already... Add `min-width: 100%` aswell as the `width:1000px;`

Comment: Glad to hear my solution worked. For people who find this page in the future, please tick this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modifie it to a percentage like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background:#339900;">
        <div style="width:80%; height:75px; background:#ff0000; margin:0px auto;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; height:200px; background:#dddddd;">
        <div style="width:80%; height:75px; background:#000000; margin:0px auto;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is normal because the green space in the minimized screen occupy 100% of this screen and the scroll bar appear because you want a red space of 1000px.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I had tried...Believe me, but I don't have "50 reputation"!!

Comment: Yes that's what I want

Comment: @Majd, but you set the percentage to `80%`, you are making the assumption 1000px is 80% of his screen; and that he is after that amount of screen, not after 1000px

Comment: @Pyro, I see a bit of ambiguity in what he exactly wants, but I made the assumption and gave a simple example (you can replace 80% by x%), maybe that could help him.

Comment: exactly Majd, I want the 100% box to take the full screen width.

Comment: It's just easy to understand that the percentage is dynamic with the screen, and not fix size in pixels... Afterwards, you can do what you want.